# Tkinter padding not changing height of button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When using the `padx` and `pady` options with tkinter buttons, the button size increases in x direction but not in y direction.

The button is only drawn larger in x direction but not in y direction. However, when clicking the space above and below the button (y padding area), the button is still clicked/active.

I am using Python 3.7 on macOS Catalina.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def Click():
    myLabel = Label(root, text = 'Button clicked.')
    myLabel.pack()


bn1 = Button(root, text='Button 1', pady=50, padx=100, command=Click)
bn1.pack()

bn2 = Button(root, text='Button 2', pady=50, padx=100, command=Click)
bn2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[Screenshot of sample programme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E35dR.png)

Comment: Are you on OSX? OSX won't let you increase the height of buttons.

Comment: Yes, I’m using OSX. Thanks. Is there a work-around? Is that on OSX issue or a Tkinter issue? Does the same happen with PyQT5?

Comment: You can use a label widget and give it bindings that mimic a button. OSX design guidelines are fairly strict in some regards, and the look of buttons is one place that they lock it down pretty tight.